# How can I send my search string from front end to back end code through Flask API

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am making an API for searching files according to the string provided by user in front end , how can I send this string to my back end code if i am using flask. Also in front end I am using java script and HTML.

Comment: how does your code look so far?

Comment: Look into HTML forms.